# Connection reset by peer socket write error

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Hi i am trying to send one big buffer in multiple packets to client machine but after 4-5 write calls i get error "Connection reset by peer socket write error". Below is my code sample

server.c

```
int main()
{
    int fd,i;
    image_info info;
    bool quit = false;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr,clint_addr;
    int sock_fd,clint_fd,n;//clen;
    socklen_t clen = 512;
    char buff[100];
    sock_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sock_fd<0)
    {
        perror("server socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    puts("server socket is created successfully\n");
    serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port=65000;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr= INADDR_ANY;
    if(bind(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    puts("bind successful\n");
    puts("listening\n");
    if(listen(sock_fd,0)<0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((fd = open("/dev/video0",O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK)) == -1)
    {
        perror("cam_info: Can't open device");
        return 1;
    }

    //printf("FD=%d\n",fd);
    init_device(fd);
    map_device(fd);
    start_capturing(fd);
    update_cam(fd);
    update_cam(fd);

    puts("waiting to accept a connection from cient\n");
    clint_fd=accept(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&clint_addr,&clen);
    if(clint_fd<0)
    {
        int errsv = errno;
        printf("Errorno:%d",errsv);
        perror("client server");
        exit(1);
    }

    info.width = 640;
    info.hight = 480;
    info.buff_size = 2*640*480;
    //uint8_t image_buff[buff_length];

    bzero(buff,100);
    n=read(clint_fd,buff,100);
    if(n<0)
    {
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    }
    puts(buff);
    n= write(clint_fd,&info,sizeof(info));
    if(n<0)
    {
        perror("write");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*for(i=0;FRAME_BUFFERS[buff_index].start[i];i++)
    {
        image_buff[i] = FRAME_BUFFERS[buff_index].start[i];
    }*/

    //printf("length = %d\n",i);
    update_cam(fd);
    for(int i=0; i<51200*12; i=i+51200)
    {
        printf("in loop=%d\n",i);
        n= write(clint_fd,FRAME_BUFFERS[buff_index].start+i,51200);
        if(n<0)
        {
            perror("write");
            exit(1);
        }

    }

    n=read(clint_fd,buff,100);
    if(n<0)
    {
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    }
    puts(buff);


    stop_capturing(fd);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

client.c

```
int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    FILE *fp;
    int sock_fd,n;
    unsigned char* rgb;
    image_info info;
    char buff[100];
    fp = fopen("sample.jpg","w+");
    sock_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sock_fd<0)
    {
        perror("server socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    puts("client socket is created successfully\n");
    serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port=65000;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("172.20.115.126");
    if(connect(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    puts("connect successful\n");
    bzero(buff,100);
    n= write(sock_fd,"connected",11);
    if(n<0)
    {
        perror("write");
        exit(1);
    }
    n=read(sock_fd,&info,sizeof(info));
    if(n<0)
    {
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("size=%d\n",info.buff_size);
    n= write(sock_fd,"data received",14);
    if(n<0)
    {
        perror("write");
        exit(1);
    }
    uint8_t image_buff[info.buff_size];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<51200*12; i=i+51200)
    {
        printf("in loop=%d\n",i);
        n=read(sock_fd,image_buff+i,51200);
        if(n<0)
        {
            perror("read");
            exit(1);
        }

    }

   /* else
    {
        printf("read successfull\n");
    }*/
    printf("successfull\n");
    rgb = (uint8_t*)yuyv2rgb(image_buff, 640, 480);
    jpeg(fp,rgb, 640, 480, 100);
    printf("successfull\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
    //printf("size=%d\n",info.buff_size);
    //printf("end");
}
```

please help me to resolve this issue..

Answer (score 1):

You didn't check the return value of `write()`. Are you assuming all the data are written, i.e. n=51200? That might not be the case. Same applies for `read()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a fundamental TCP error in this code. You are assuming that if you send a 100 byte `write` that you will then get a 100 byte `read`. This is not so. Usually if programs are on the same machine it will work because those boundaries usually work but not over a real network.

TCP is a stream protocol , not a record oriented one. The only guarantees are

- the bytes you send will be received in the same order they were sent
- they will be received only once

YOu could send 100 bytes and get 20 5 byte `read`s

So you must do this to `read`

```
bzero(buff,100);
int offset = 0;
int len = ???;
while(true){
  n=read(clint_fd,buff + offset,100 - offset);
 
  if(n<0)
  {
     perror("read");
     exit(1);
   }
  len -= n;
  offset += n;
  if (len == 0)
    break;
}
```

ie keep looping till you have received all the data. Note that this requires you to know the length of the message you are going to receive. Either you must know it implicitly (first message is always 100 bytes) or you must transmit the length first. Or detect the end of a message by looking for a specifc sequence (like HTTPs \r\n\r\n)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by writing to a connection that had already been closed by the peer.

In this case it is probably caused by not reading all the input before you close. You're ignoring the result returned by `read()` apart from checking it for -1, so you're assuming it fills the buffer. It isn't obliged to do that, or to transfer more than one byte at a time. You need to loop until you've received all the data you're expecting. That in turn may mean that you need to send the length of the data being written ahead of the data.

Comment: Hi that same program is working if i use loophole IP

Comment: That only proves that it's unstable. Any time it works, it is relying on special cases.

Comment: And you didn't check for end of stream in `read()`. You can't assume a hardcoded number of bytes will be received. Nor can you assume that `read()` will fill the buffer. And you certainly won't receive 51200 bytes per read over a TCP socket.